# How to create a 30 day Running total on views when views aren't totaled by day in original table - Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, cumulative-sum

I'm looking to count all pageviews that occurred in the previous 30 days for each article each day.

My data set looks as follows. Every pageview that occurs, a new row is added with the date and time it was received, the article id the view occurred for, and some additional info not needed for this analysis. Since I don't have a daily sum of pageviews for each article it makes this problem more difficult to solve

```
received_at                   article_id other_info_1 other_info_2
----------                    ---------- ------------ ------------
2017-01-04 04:03:01 +0000        987         17         desktop
2017-01-05 07:03:23 +0000        987         23          mobile
2017-01-03 01:09:10 +0000        123          1          mobile
2017-02-20 11:32:20 +0000        123         17          desktop
2017-02-01 09:03:01 +0000        123         17          tablet
2017-01-04 04:11:04 +0000        567         17          desktop
```

What I'd like to get is something like the following

```
article_id         date         Previous 30 day count
----------         ----         ---------------------
123              2017-02-20             90
123              2017-02-19            130
123              2017-02-18             45
456              2017-02-20             10
456              2017-02-19            100
456              2017-02-18             89
789              2017-02-20            235
789              2017-02-19            130
789              2017-02-18             89
```

Each day I'd like to have the total views that occurred in the previous 30 days for that article

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that each article is viewed at least once every day, then you can do a cumulative sum:

```
select trunc(received_at) as dte, article_id,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by article_id
                           order by trunc(received_at)
                           rows between 29 preceding and current row
                          ) as prev_30_day_count
from t
group by dte, article_id
order by dte, article_id;
```

Without at least one view per day, this won't work so well.  Probably the best approach in Redshift is to actually create the data:

```
select a.article_id, d.dte, count(t.article_id) as day_views,
       sum(count(t.article_id)) over (partition by a.article_id
                                      order by d.dte
                                      rows between 29 preceding and current row
                                     ) as prev_30_day_count
from (select distinct trunc(received_at) as dte from t) d cross join
     (select distinct article_id from t) a left join
     t
     on d.dte = trunc(t.received_at) and a.article_id = t.article_id
group by d.dte, t.article_id;
```

This assumes at least one view on any article each day.

Comment: If you have another table for article IDs, you can use that table inner joined with a tally or numbers table and left join with your pageviews table, coalesce any nulls to zeroes (for articles not having any pageviews for a given day) - you can then use sum over () as shown in Gordons first query